# SQL: get a substring by removing character off the right and left

Tags: sql, string, substring, hive

I have a column of values like:

```
 [{"run_status":1,"daily_budget":"2000","campaign_id":"60952315"}].
```

What is the query for removing the first and last bracket, so I am left with

```
 {"run_status":1,"daily_budget":"2000","campaign_id":"60952315"}
```

If your answer is dependent on SQL version, I am using Hive.

Comment: "Hive defines a simple _SQL-like_ query language, called QL, that enables users familiar with SQL to query the data."
http://hive.apache.org/docs/r0.9.0/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

String operations in databases often vary among the different versions.  In Hive, you want:

```
select substr(<val>, 2, length(<val>) - 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUBSTR:

SUBSTR( string source_str, int start_position [,int length]  ),  SUBSTRING( string source_str, int start_position [,int length]  )

http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/string-functions-in-hive.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the quick and dirty of it, but an alternative would be to create an array of values to replace and iterate through them.

```
    declare @origString varchar(150)
        ,@newString varchar(150)
        , @replace varchar(10)
        , @replace2 varchar(10)
        , @replaceValue varchar(10)

    set @replaceValue =''
    set @replace = '['
    set @replace2 =']'
    set @origString = '[{"run_status":1,"daily_budget":"2000","campaign_id":"60952315"}]'

    select REPLACE(REPLACE(@origString, @replace, @replaceValue), @replace2, @replaceValue)
```

Comment: Iterate is the wrong word (usually) to use in an SQL context.  This setup is also only safe so long as the only place those two characters appear is at the start/end of the stored string - if it's anywhere else, your results are 'undefined'.

Comment: Thanks for the information, developer answering a sql question (write all my own queries, sp, etc.) so terms like iterate come naturally.  I'm always willing to learn, so if iterate is incorrect in this context, what would be the correct term? Loop?  Also, If I may ask, how would you go about writing the sql for the presented problem?  Again, a developer always willing to learn new ways of thinking about a problem.

Comment: As others have posted, `SUBSTR()` (especially if it is indeed, only the first/last characters) is likely to be the better choice.  'Iterate' suggests that the same function is being performed (singly) on multiple lines.  Your nested `REPLACE()` doesn't strike me as fulfilling this requirement.  Also, because SQL is supposed to be _set_ based, actual iteration (with an actual loop construct) is almost always the **wrong** thing to do.  Approaching SQL like an imperative program is likely to end up fighting the engine.